# JSX element type 'App' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, higher-order-components

I'm rewriting my React app to Typescript and having trouble rewriting my HOC. It's a HOC for session. The following is my `withSession.tsx` HOC:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { selectors } from 'redux/tokens'
import { Tokens } from 'redux/tokens/types'
import { SessionContext } from 'contexts/sessionContext'

const withSession = () => {
  const WithSession = <T extends Tokens>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>): React.FC<T & Tokens> => {
    return ({accessToken, refreshToken, expiry, ...props}: Tokens) => {
      return (
        <SessionContext.Provider value={{accessToken, refreshToken, expiry}}>
          <WrappedComponent {...props as T} />
        </SessionContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
      tokens: selectors.tokens(state),
    }
  }

  const withSessionConnected = connect<any, {}, any>(
    mapStateToProps,
  )(WithSession as any)

  return withSessionConnected
}

export default withSession
```

And my `App.ts` like so:

```
import withSession from 'hocs/withSession'

const App: React.FC<Props> = ({test}: Props) => {
  return <div>This is my App</div>
}

export default withSession()(App)
```

Could anyone help me figure out why it's complaining that `App` does not have any construct or call signatures? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by non-explicit export of `App` component as `React.ComponentType` or `React.Element`. At least that's what helped me in very similar situation when dealing with HOC.

```
import withSession from 'hocs/withSession'

const App: React.FC<Props> = ({test}: Props) => {
  return <div>This is my App</div>
}

export default withSession()(App) as React.ComponentType
```